# I can't replicate the following navigation bar, tried everything. [Bootstrap 3 nav]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been working on this for the past 4 hours. Tried literally everything but I can't replicate this navigation bar.

[image]

This navigation bar has a HTML like this;

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) <!-- below loops 3 times for testing purposes -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                      //Styling goes here.
                </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        @endfor
    </ul>
</div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
```

It works like this:

1. `li` tag has transparent, circle background on itself. (e.g `<li class="blue">` has blue circle)
2. Transparent house icons being placed on those circle backgrounds. (They need to be centered on circle, probably requires some margin hacking?)
3. `Konut` is a menu name, meaning `House` (type doesn't matter, I tried using `h4` and `span`)
4. Numbers below is the amount of total listings. (which is basically a span)

I rewrote my navigation bar like 10 times. Tried block level image div, inline-block divs, margin hacks, relative positioning, absolute positioning, using box models... I'm really about to rip my hair.

[The live version can be found here](http://www.hurriyetemlak.com/) (I can't understand much from their styling)

Can anyone give me a JsFiddle example or tell me what I should be doing? Or is my HTML markup problematic?

Thank you.

Ps. I use Bootstrap 3, if it matters.

Comment: Why don't you give us the jsfiddle of what you have so far, and we might take over from there?

Comment: It's pretty hacky since I rewrote it like 10 times or so. I can probably find a good looking version if I rewing my IDE for a while.

Comment: Yeah, that would be really helpful, because this doesn't seem like a hard thing to do. The key is in using proper background-positions to represent proper image in a proper place (getting way to proper here). Nothing more. No margin hacking needed, just combine padding with background-position.

Comment: Not the best, but I found this in history. http://jsfiddle.net/XryQ4/ Make sure you increase the size of "Result" pane. I don't know how reliable this is, had to spam Control Z for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, here's what you should do:

You need to make a right spritesheet. Note how the distance of elements in the original ones is just like the height of the navbar. It's not mandatory, but it fixes vertical positioning/cropping issues that might arise.

Like you sait:

- li tag has transparent, circle background on itself. `background-position derived from class`
- Transparent house icons being placed on those circle backgrounds. `background-position + padding`
- Konut is a menu name, meaning House `nothing special here`
- Numbers below is the amount of total listings. `also nothing special here, just be careful to position it properly`

This is just a list of things you need to know for this. I'll expand my answer once I see what have you done so far.

Of course, if you prefer not to use a spritesheet, but separate images, that's fine too. The only difference would be that you'd specify your background images by their URLs, while the site you gave us is specifying them by their spritesheet position.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I can't provide you a better example than I posted on comments section. My IDE doesn't support any more history than this.

Comment: Hm, that's just the most basic code... Can you follow the guidelines I gave you, at least add some image backgrounds, try to position things right... There's a lot of work there, and SO is for solving problems, not writing the whole code.

Comment: I'll try to replicate this using the information you gave me. Do I need any blocks or inline blocks inside the `li`?

Comment: No, just follow the structure they have. At least try to add proper images to the jsfiddle.

Comment: @Chris Very nice, using CSS background and border-radius to get almost the same look. OP: You can extend those h3.heading elements by adding them a padding and a background image (the circle), just like I told you. Then replace the text in the span element with the menu icon and you'll have exactly the same navbar like the one you've shown us.

Comment: Thanks alot Chris. I've done the following right now: http://jsfiddle.net/FNnmq/ It doesn't look cool for some reason.

Comment: @Imaqtpie Two minor changes to your mockup help: http://jsfiddle.net/FNnmq/2/ -- changed the background size on the main bar, and changed the hover effects on the `li/li>a`. Main thing is -- get Firebug, set up your demo, then spend some time tweaking. It is just a matter of attention to detail and experimentation :)

Comment: @Chris Thanks alot Chris. I'll study your fiddle right now and see what you did differently. I guess I'm going to accept Shomz's post as the answer since you both helped me alot. :)

Comment: @Imaqtpie No problem! I tweaked it a little more (wasting time waiting for a build!): http://jsfiddle.net/abnEY/1/

Comment: @Chris Awesome!! This answer should've been yours.